# Changing value of 2D array coordinate

Tags: arrays, c

I have created a 2D array of zeros using while loops and I would like to change specific coordinates into 1s. I have tried manually typing in coordinates but for some reason it does not affect the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int map[10][10]);

int main (void) {
    int map[10][10] = {};
    map[4][4] = 1;
    print(map);
    return 0;
}

void print(int map[10][10]) {
    int row = 0;
    while (row < 10) {
        int col = 0;
        while (col < 10) {
            printf("0 ");
            col++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        row++;
    }
}
```

I was intending for coordinate of the 5th column and 5th row to turn into a 1, but the array printed is still a zero. (^^this is written in c)

Thank you

Comment: You're literally printing a bunch of zeros no matter what: `printf("0 ");`

Answer (score 2):

You are simply printing `0` instead of printing values in the array in this line:

```c
            printf("0 ");
```

Change the line to print the values in the array:

```c
            printf("%d ", map[row][col]);
```